# Copy a source file to another destination in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs, fs-extra

I'm trying to copy an image from a folder to another using fs-extra module .

```
var fse = require('fs-extra');

function copyimage() {
  fse.copy('mainisp.jpg', './test', function (err) {     
    if (err) 
      return console.error(err)
  });
}
```

This is my directory
[image]

and this is the error I get all the time:

> Error {errno: -4058, code: "ENOENT", syscall: "lstat", path:
>   "E:\mainisp.jpg", message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
>   'E:\mainisp.jpg'"}

[image]

and by changing destination to `./test/` I get this error

> Error {errno: -4058, code: "ENOENT", syscall: "lstat", path:
>   "E:\Development\Node apps\Node softwares\Digital_library\mainisp.jpg",
>   message: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Devel…
>   apps\Node softwares\Digital_library\mainisp.jpg'"}

Note: I'm not testing this in browser. It's an Nwjs app and the pics of error attached are from Nwjs console.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

fs.copySync(path.resolve(__dirname,'./mainisp.jpg'), './test/mainisp.jpg');
```

As you can see in the error message, you're trying to read the file from `E:\mainisp.jpg` instead of the current directory.

You also need to specify the target path with the file, not only the destination folder.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply ! but the src file is in the same dir of javascript file so path could be only the name as we use it in Html or css . and i am not getting this thing "target path with the file " !

Comment: can you please show the exact path with above code  that i should use . Image of directory is attached ! please

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain the target path must be `./test/mainisp.jpg` isntead of `./test`. You need to specicfy the file, not just the directory.

Comment: and this __dirname ??? what should come here ? getting this error in nodejs test ReferenceError: path is not defined !

Answer (score 21):

You can do this using the native `fs` module easily using streams.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let filename = 'mainisp.jpg';
let src = path.join(__dirname, filename);
let destDir = path.join(__dirname, 'test');

fs.access(destDir, (err) => {
  if(err)
    fs.mkdirSync(destDir);

  copyFile(src, path.join(destDir, filename));
});


function copyFile(src, dest) {

  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(src);

  readStream.once('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  readStream.once('end', () => {
    console.log('done copying');
  });

  readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest));
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work ! ' .. i copied and pasted your code in my function and still getting 100% second error i have mentioned a above .

Comment: This code does work, you're just experiencing an error because the destination directory doesn't exist. At least thats what your error you've provided said. The directory path that you'd like doesn't get created along with the file. The containing folder still needs to exist prior to the file being copied.

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain added directory check before starting.

Comment: please look at the image of directory i have attached with question. The destination folder /test exists already !

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain this code will 100% work for that directory setup.

Comment: believe me bro ! i just tested your updated code and 100% same error 4058 ! :( my directory is same as shown in pic but still error !

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain have you tried running this with plain Node.js?

Comment: well no ! i am going to try this now ! i will tell you the result .

Comment: tested ! gives syntex error ! SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: You're running an older version of node then, just convert the syntax to use var instead and get rid of the arrow functions.

Comment: OMG ! finally i got it :) thanks a lot bro.. but actually .. the problem was the source and destination path should be : Src =>  E:/Development/Node apps/Node softwares/Digital_library/html/js/test/mainisp.jpg  and Dest => E:/Development/Node apps/Node softwares/Digital_library/html/js/mainisp.jpg........... it requires full address for both src and dest ! i am accepting your answer but please edit  it so that others can get benefit of it :) and maye you can upvote my question :D

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain updated my answer to include more generic pathing

Comment: I have used this way and it works but it destroys the timestamp data, is there a way to keep the original creation time and modifications time of the files?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.copyFileSync(src, dest);
```